# Aerospike geoNear feature vs MongoDB geoNear query

Tags: mongodb, postgis, aerospike

We have the use case where We have to out perform mongoDB 2dsphere indexed geoNear queries. We found that Aerospike has recently launched geoNear features, considering it has proven benchmarking results, we want to get few opinions on that.

As per our benchmarking for geoNear queries on Aerospike, it's performance degrade with increasing radius. Has anyone faced same issue ?

It will be great if someone can share Aerospike benchmarking results for geo queries.

Also has anyone explored postgis vs aerospike vs mongodb for same usecase ?

Answer (score 1):

In Aerospike you can build a [GEO2DSPHERE index](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/geospatial.html) over record bins that contain GeoJSON data. You can currently perform two types of geospatial queries over such an index - points within a region, and regions containing a point. There is no support for a geoNear query. I'm not really sure how you're benchmarking something that doesn't exist. Do you mean a points-within-a-region query using the AeroCircle type for the region, such as the Python client's [`aerospike.predicates.geo_within_radius`](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/predicates.html#aerospike.predicates.geo_within_radius)?

Aerospike has a limited set of GeoJSON types and queries, but for those it has significantly better performance than MongoDB.

Comment: Check out the [announcement for Aerospike 3.8](http://www.aerospike.com/blog/aerospike-3-8-release/).

Comment: Ronen I meant same thing aerospike.predicates.geo_within_radius. It's performance degrades as radius size increases